# jenkins - maven - sonar 3.7

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

we had

Jenkins 1.513 - Maven 3.0.5 - Sonar 3.5

combo setup for our projects.

After upgrading Sonar to version 3.7 i get the following error, on all projects:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project RC: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Unable to execute Sonar: Task null does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project RC: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
...
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Task null does not exist
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
```

Now, i get that it's a NullPointerException, but i couldn't find what/where to do to make things works again.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Thank you,
Marian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so obviously the error was human:

I should've understood, not just read this particular line:

> **If for any reason,  has to change (moving the SonarQube distribution into another directory, generating the WAR and deploying it on different machines, etc.), set the SONAR_HOME environment variable to the new path to .**

from the

[Deploying SonarQube on Tomcat](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Deploying+SonarQube+on+Tomcat) documentation.

Since I was doing an upgrade, i didn't want to remove the Sonar's old installation just yet, so i installed the new version in sonar-3.7 without updating the $SONAR_HOME variable which pointed to the /sonar folder (doh)

I found out after my initial post that the above mentioned error occured only when running SonarQube as webapp in Tomcat. In standalone mode, it was running fine.

Maybe this is one of the reasons why it is stated :

> **Note that the support of Tomcat will be dropped in version 4.1 of SonarQube.
>   Thus, it is highly recommended to stick with the standalone mode and not deploy SonarQube on Tomcat.**

on the mentioned page.

It's easier to make an application more stupid proof just saying "don't do that" rather than fixing your own NullPointerExceptions. The only risk with this approach is that the stupid must understand what he's reading.